# How do I install npm & composer dependencies on a AWS Elasticbeanstalk Multi-Container Docker app via the Dockerfile?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, elastic-beanstalk

#### Expected result

Would you please advise on how to install npm and composer dependencies in my webroot via the `Dockerfile` on a AWS Elasticbeanstalk Multi-Container Docker app?

#### Current situation

I've been building my files from within the docker container via the Dockerfile with code like this:

```
// Dockerfile
...

# npm
WORKDIR /var/www/tmp_html
RUN mkdir -p npm
WORKDIR /var/www/tmp_html/npm
COPY php-app/package.json package.json
RUN npm update && npm install

# composer
... // similar to above

# Switch working directory back to webroot
WORKDIR /var/www/html
```

After deployment, when I ssh into the instance's `php:fpm` container, i can see the following structure:

```
root@3f8bf1xc2a78:/var/www# ls
html  tmp_html
```

The built files are in /tmp_html and i'm trying to move them into /html. via my Dockerfile like this:

```
ONBUILD RUN mv -v ../tmp_html/composer/protected/vendor/* protected/vendor \
    && rm -rf ../tmp_html/composer/protected \
    && mv -v ../tmp_html/composer/* . \
    && mv -v ../tmp_html/npm/* . \
    && rm -rf ../tmp_html
```

#### Problem

Problem is, the ONBUILD step is not working. On Docker Inspect the php:fpm container, i noticed this: "OnBuild": null. It seems like the onbuild didn't even run. The files in the the `/html` and `/tmp_html` folders remain the same.

Furthermore, if i RUN the commands plainly without the ONBUILD command, on docker push to the docker image repository, the target location cannot be detected and refuses to let me push so i can't even deploy. The error is:
`mv: target 'protected/vendor' is not a directory`
 I guess this is because elasticbeanstalk hasn't copied the bundle in, so at this point the html folder isn't even available.

Answer (score 0):

Stop with the temporary directory. Copy the files into the image where you need them and then when building the image install your npm modules and your composer modules.

Not sure why you want to have them in temp folder then move them?